# Speed up Risk wargame dice rolling simulation

Tags: python, performance, dice

Friends and I were wondering what the % chance of victory was in various situations in the board game, Risk, which involves a world war over an Earth-like board divided into territories.

For those unfamiliar with Risk:

In each turn of the game an attacker can decide to invade a defender's country on the board.  The attacker and defender choose how many dice to use for the battle.  For example the attacker can in some situations decide to attack with 3 dice and the defender might choose to defend with 2 dice.

```
Attacker rolls 3 dice and gets 6,4,1
Defender rolls 2 dice and gets 6,3

If the same number is rolled, defender always wins, so in this situation,
 we compare the attacker's two highest rolls against the defender's.
The defender's 6 beats the attacker's 6 and
 the attacker's 4 beats the defender's 3.
```

In this case each side loses 1 army.  This could continue with more dice rolls until the attacker stops attacking or runs out of armies, but at this point I am only interested in the frequency of wins on single tosses of the dice.

So I wrote a batch to simulate many times rather than entering the counterintuitive world of probabilities. I'm fairly new to coding so I'm looking for tips on efficiency.  I am yet to fathom multiprocessing so we'll leave that out for now if that's ok.

I was surprised at how long it took to do one million simulations (around 20 seconds) and was wondering if there's something I'm doing wrong or if this is the sort of time you might expect from such a routine.

Here's the simulation part:

```
from random import randint

  # Pass in number of each dice and number of sim's
def simulate(attDice,defDice,rolls):
    attLosses = 0
    defLosses = 0
    for roll in rolls:               # Number of simulations
        attRolls = []                # List holding attack dice 'scores'
        for die in range(attDice):   # Number of attack dice rolled
            attRolls.append(randint(1,6))
        defRolls = []                #  List holding defence dice 'scores'
        for die in range(defDice):   # Number of defence dice rolled
            defRolls.append(randint(1,6))
        while len(attRolls) and len(defRolls): # For each 
            if max(attRolls) > max(defRolls):  # Att's must beat def's
                defLosses += 1
            else:
                attLosses += 1
            # Delete the highest number from each list
            del(attRolls[attRolls.index(max(attRolls))])  # This seems clumsy
            del(defRolls[defRolls.index(max(defRolls))])  # which is what makes me
                                                      # think there's a better way
    return attLosses,defLosses
# We then go and work out percentages etc.
```

Comment: This looks incorrect `for die in defRolls: ` because defRolls is an empty [].  Shouldn't it be `range(defDice)` ?

Comment: @Paul Yes, thank you. I'm trying to remember it rather than copy/paste as I don't currently have access to it.

Comment: Numpy is useful.  `numpy.random.randint(1,6,size=(1000000,3))` runs 3000000 dice rolls in under a second here.  The problem is coding the army win-loss logic in numpy.

Comment: @Paul Oh that's nice - I'll bear it in mind!
Yeah, it would be fine if it was always the same number of dice - could just roll them all at once - but 3v2 or any other combination and the probabilities are skewed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are in effect sorting the dice lists, it is better to use python's sort function which is fast.

Generating random numbers is also relatively slow. By only generating one number for all the dice you can accelerate it somewhat.

This runs in ~5s on my computer for a million rolls if attDice and defDice are smallish (<=5). (With PyPy it runs in 1s.)

```
def freqs(attDice, defDice, rolls):
    m = min(attDice, defDice)
    freq = [0]*(m+1)
    for i in range(rolls):
        ar = random.randrange(6**attDice)
        dr = random.randrange(6**defDice)
        ad = [(ar / 6**j) % 6 for j in range(attDice)]
        ad.sort(reverse=True)
        dd = [(dr / 6**j) % 6 for j in range(defDice)]
        dd.sort(reverse=True)
        aws = sum(j > k for j, k in zip(ad, dd))
        freq[aws] += 1
    return freq
```

It returns a frequency table of attacker wins.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of handwaving, totally unrigorous answer.

I'm not surprised with ~20s for one million rounds. I've done similar experiments/simulations in Python with the same experience. Granted, those experiments are not really time critical so I did not optimize.

And Python isn't really known for speed. Maybe you're used to lower-level languages. If you did the same experiment in Java, I *would be* surprised if it took you as long.

(If you really want to speed this up, maybe some context in your question will help? Your purpose seems casual so aside from some constant-time speed-ups and maybe some micro-optimizations, I see little to change.)

Comment: Thanks for that - I only have experience with python and a ZOPL-based language and have no experience in anything else as yet.  Your answer gives some context to python as a whole so thank you.

Comment: Python is often slower than Java, but it isn't *that* slow. There's every chance this problem can be solved in a way that is very fast even in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the start of a numpy implementation for 1,000,000 rolls.

I've marked this community wiki if someone wants to expand it, edit away.

3 attack dice, 2 defend dice

```
import numpy
A = numpy.random.randint(1,6,size=(1000000,3)).sort()
D = numpy.random.randint(1,6,size=(1000000,2)).sort()
Ahigh = A[:,2]
Dhigh = D[:,2]
Awins1st = (Ahigh > Dhigh)
A2nd = A[:,1]
D2nd = D[:,1]
Awins2nd = (A2nd > D2nd)
# needed: tabulate results, remove smelly repeating code, generalize
```

`Awins1st` and `Awins2nd` are 1000000 element true/false arrays, indicating whether the attacker won the 1st or 2nd "battle" from comparing the 3 A dice to the 2 D dice.